# convert String in unknown format

Tags: hash, sha256, sha2

i have this string in sha256

**3249c65b5da8899116f55e99c000467c28e6dc4fb955e666f61c40068284bce7**

And I could not turn it converted in this formula

**1436328553-oALyBXPB7Pl88GTlICgFOWQbgbCnb7X6mLIldxlbBxq5Gfkqng6LnWHf2YLA5P58-134303-1342760**

watch the second string egal of this

**7a918b6eaac0c00abc20463adcbe0a7424ebc2647c0f96e79a7ce8d16e1c0f9b**

but to the Hmac512 Hashing i will convert the first to second format to get the valid hash

please help me i'm **beginner** please

thnx

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: thanks for reply me . i'm asking how i can convert the sha256 string in the second format.

Comment: But what is the second "format"? Is it another hashing result? A random string?

Comment: i don't know but this is the problem. server send me the first string ,and i will convert it to the second

Comment: ok please tell me How can I convert to the first in base64

Comment: Sha output is binary, the first and third strings are hexadecimal so it may be the hex representation of a sha256 result. Base64 is another way to express binary data in ascii but using a set of more than 16 different chars so it may be shorter than hexadecimal. To convert from hex to base64 by code you should decode the hex to bin and then to base64. This web site let you test it online. http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en

Comment: thank you mr but the second is alphanmeric string
show this exemple
string 1 alphanmeric
1436312693-0kZXuFnACHscE~dp1K-Q~gPINYp2rDyn.D6_o0uvYQNlQ7XE8hBq8_8O-xocchAJ-134289-1342760
= string 2 in Base64
MTQzNjMxMjY5My0wa1pYdUZuQUNIc2NFfmRwMUstUX5nUElOWXAyckR5bi5ENl9vMHV2WVFObFE3WEU4aEJxOF84Ty14b2NjaEFKLTEzNDI4OS0xMzQyNzYw
= string 3 in sha256
865d6615d5a26146dd6e229613d0dfcc810c901ceeeaa547864043292dca5698
sow How to order from sha256 to get the alphanumiric string this is the problem

Comment: im sorry she is not alphanumeric she is unkonuwn :p